# reload page after ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to reload a page upon ajax response but its flickering page but its not refreshing or reloading page, Below is my code.

```
function callAjaxForCount(getCountValue){
    var maxValue = getCountValue;
    var interval = 3000; 
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ServletToCheckCondition",
        async: false,
        data: {"totalLoggedMembers": maxValue},
        success: function(data) {
            for (var key in data) {
            var retValue = data[key];       

                if(retValue == 'true')
                {

                  location.reload();
                }
                else if(retValue == 'false')
                {

                }
            }
            },
        error: function() {
            alert("Failed. Try Again.","error");
        },
        complete: function () {
        // Schedule the next
        window.setInterval(callAjaxForCount(maxValue),interval);
         }
        });
    }
```

This is in a window.open popup window and this function will call when popup starts and keep calling for every 3 seconds repeatedly if the condition satisfies and returns true then page has to reload and it will set new value to page dynamically, But page is not refreshing its flickering continuously.

I used location.reload() , i also tried to keep a hidden button and submitting page but no luck.

Comment: sometimes  location.reload() donot work in chrome try  window.location.reload(true)

Comment: If you want to reload the page, why do ajax at all, do a regular form submit and the page will reload automagically

Comment: @Kartikeya i tried still the same.. i tried in other browser also its still the same issue

Comment: @adeneo this is because i dont want to keep querying db for ever second, i wanted to refresh page only when new value added into table.then refresh page and get all other table values.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function callAjaxForCount(getCountValue){
var maxValue = getCountValue;
var interval = 3000; 
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/ServletToCheckCondition",
    async: false,
    data: {"totalLoggedMembers": maxValue},
    success: function(data) {
        for (var key in data) {
        var retValue = data[key];       

            if(retValue == 'true')
            {

               window.location.reload();
            }
            else if(retValue == 'false')
            {

            }
        }
        },
    error: function() {
        alert("Failed. Try Again.","error");
    },
    complete: function () {
    // Schedule the next
    window.setInterval(callAjaxForCount(maxValue),interval);
     }
    });
}
```

Comment: No luck , its still the same.